# A negative question

Tags: questions, british-english

Good morning.

How to ask a negative question in British English.

> Didn't you hear it ?
>
> Don't you have it ?
>
> Doesn't she love him ?

etc.. Please, can you explain it to me ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I think English grammar is ver straightfofward in this case. What is your problem in particular? Please pinpoint a specific problem by adding further details

Comment: I ask if those forms are correct. Is it usual in British English ?

Comment: There are a number of web sites that offer explanations of negative questions in English. For starters you might try: http://www.englishgrammar.org/negative-questions/   and   https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/verbs-questions-and-negatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the slightly more verbose:

> You did hear that, didn't you?

It's basically asking for confirmation that you heard something. It's used when the questioner believes they are correct and seeks confirmation. Often it's a rhetorical question, and it's mostly a way of saying "I think I heard something".

The shorter form: "Didn't you hear it?" is similar. The questioner thinks you heard something (or should have heard it) and wishes to confirm that this is indeed the case.

In spoken British English, the tone used to ask the question is paramount, and can indicate shock / anger / surprise / doubt as to what your thoughts are.